# Error al asignar valor a label en PyQt5 y Python2

Tags: python, pyqt5, python-2.x

Tengo una ventana de autenticación con usuario, *pass* e *ip de servidor*, además una *label (mlogin)*, la autenticación se realiza contra servidor *ldap*, al entrar en el *except*, me lanza una excepción de que mi clase `no login`, no posee atributo *mlogin*.

Aquí parte del código:

```
searchScope = ldap.SCOPE_SUBTREE
retrieveAttributes = None
searchFilter = "(uid=%s, servicio=cat)" % (str(self.usuario))
dn = "uid=%s,%s" % (self.usuario, baseDN)
self.ui.mlogin.setText("")

if (self.usuario != "") and (self.contrasena != "") : 
    self.ui.mlogin.setText=""                  
    try:
        self.conexionServidor = ldap.initialize(self.servidor_url)
        self.conexionServidor.set_option(ldap.OPT_PROTOCOL_VERSION,3)
        self.conexionServidor.simple_bind_s(dn,self.contrasena)
    except  ldap.NO_SUCH_OBJECT:
        self.conexionServidor.unbind()                    
        self.usur1 = ""
        self.ui.mLogin.setText("NO EXISTE EL USUARIO")
        self.ui.eUsuario.setFocus()
        return
    except ldap.INVALID_CREDENTIALS:
        self.conexionServidor.unbind()
        self.usur1 = ''
        self.ui.mLogin.setText("PASSWORD INCORRECTO")
        self.ui.eUsuario.setFocus()
        return
    except ldap.SERVER_DOWN:
        self.conexionServidor.unbind()                    
        self.usur1 = ''
        self.ui.mLogin.setText('PROBLEMAS CON SERVIDOR LDAP')
        self.ui.eUsuario.setFocus()
        return
```

Tengo el siguiente error:

> File "princp.py", line 158, in acepta
> self.ui.mLogin.setText("PASSWORD INCORRECTO")
> AttributeError: 'Ui_login' object has no attribute 'mLogin'

Answer (score 0):

creo que estas escribiendo mal el nombre del atributo

```
self.ui.mlogin
```

no

```
self.ui.mLogin
```

Comment: toda la razón, no lo veía, muchas gracias

Comment: @ghd ¿Se solucionó el problema con ese cambio? Si es así podrías marcar la respuesta como correcta.